# Quarkus+Atmosphere fails with 'Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage.'

Tags: quarkus

I am unable to use the Atmosphere library (version 2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1) with Quarkus 1.10.5.Final.

I've added the `quarkus-undertow-websockets` artifact to my Vaadin Quarkus project, however the jsr356 support fails to initialize with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:53)
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:42)
```

Quick investigation shows that at Atmosphere's JSR356AsyncSupport:47 the ServerContainer is not present in the context (`ServerContainer container = (ServerContainer) ctx.getAttribute(ServerContainer.class.getName());` returns null).

That causes Atmosphere to fall back to `Servlet30CometSupport` which doesn't seem to support websockets.

Is there any way to enable websockets on Quarkus' embedded Undertow servlet container please? I've enabled the async support on QuarkusVaadinServlet to true (        `servletProducer.produce(ServletBuildItem.builder(QuarkusVaadinServlet.class.getName(), QuarkusVaadinServlet.class.getName()).addMapping("/*").setAsyncSupported(true).build());`) to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `UndertowWebsocketProcessor.java` won't create `WebSocketDeploymentInfo` which in turn causes `io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap.handleDeployment()` to not to initialize websockets, unless there is at least one websocket endpoint or websocket config in the app.

The workaround is to introduce a dummy config class:

```java
public class EnableWebsockets implements ServerApplicationConfig {
    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> endpointClasses) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-quarkus/issues/12 for more details.